# One word that means "something that is standard/uniform and meant to be copied and modified as needed"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is one word that means "something that is standard/uniform and meant to be copied and modified as needed" Like a spreadsheet that has all the basic info and only requires unique data.

Comment: Are you looking for *template*?

Comment: Another related term is "boilerplate".  Has a few different meanings, but one is a large volume of text that is copied en masse, without modification.

Answer (score 5):

### Template.

E.g. from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/template):

> anything that determines or serves as a pattern; a model
>
> [...]
>
> an electronic file with a predesigned, customized format and structure, as for a fax, letter, or expense report, ready to be filled in

Comment: YES! Thank you so  much! I have had a brainfart all day, and the word "template" was right on the tip of my tongue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In word processing/publishing, this is called a template.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(word_processing).

A magazine, for example, runs a monthly column by a particular writer. The text will change every month, but the graphics, the layout, the author's biography, etc., will always be the same or very close to the same, because these elements are saved in a template.

Answer (score 0):

The adjective that means "that is standard/uniform and meant to be copied and modified as needed" is **customizable** (*able to be changed in order to be suitable for a particular usage or situation*).

Answer (score 0):

### Boilerplate

[From The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boilerplate):

> 4. Standardized or set language that is meant to be used repeatedly, often in organizational publications or legal documents: "This was the
>      story he told her ... when they first met and the story he stuck to,
>      the original boilerplate" (Philip Roth).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_%28text%29) also has a longer and more in-depth review of the usage and etymology: